# ¿Por que se muestra este if?

Tags: php, if

Tengo este if, que supuestamente si `NO` es domingo y es cierta fecha se tiene que mostrar, eso funciona, pero necesito editar la fecha asi, por variables, y al cambiarla por variables se muestra siempre, como si la condicion se cumpliera, y no es así:

```html
$vd="01";
$vm="08";
$suma="4";
$vdr= $vd+$suma;

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                  <?php
                  if($quediaes!="Sun"  && "08-08-2018" <= $fecha || $fecha <= "$vdr-$vm-2018"){
                   include('domingo.php'); 
                 }
                   ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parece tu problema es de lógica en el uso de las variables, ya que intentas sumar 2 `string`, cuando solo los concatenan, es decir, como los valores de las variables están entre comillas, entonces los concatenas `$vd+$suma;`.

Como resultado arrojará `"01"+"4" = "014"`. Entonces, si quieres hacer operaciones matemáticas con las variables debes ponerlos sin las comillas dobles `""`:

Ejemplo:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
//sumas o restas dias, en este caso el estamos 8 dias teniendo en cuenta que hoy estamos a 9
$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '-8 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
//sumas o restas meses
// $nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
//sumas o restas años
// $nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+2 year' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
// deja la que necesites y aqui le das el nuevo valor
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha );



<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
          <?php
//primero comparas que $quediaes sea diferente "Sun", luego en el otro parentesis que alguna de las dos fechas sean inferiores
          if($quediaes!="Sun"  && ("01-05-2018" >= $fecha || $fecha <= $nuevafecha)){
           include('domingo.php'); 
         }
           ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Nota:** viendo que lo que necesitas es operar con las fechas, aquí modifico la respuesta en el cual puedes jugar con las fechas, y el condicional para el rango de fechas seria así, para que la variable `$fecha` este en ese rango de tiempo.

Comment: Mira, me da este error: PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal in .../../.. in line 29.  Mi linea 29: $vm= 08;

Comment: Lo probé eliminando esa varibale y poniendo directamente "08", igual lo muestra, y no se está cumpliendo la condicion...

Comment: que valor tiene `$fecha`?

Comment: La variable? $fecha = date("d-m-Y");

Comment: mira ahi actualice la respuesta, asi deberia de funcionar, ademas dime que trae `$quediaes`?

Comment: por otro lado siempre van a entrar bro, ya que `"08-08-2018" <= $fecha` siempre va a ser verdadero, ya que estas diciendo si `"08-08-2018"` es menor o igual a la fecha acutal, la cual es `"09-09-2018"` lo cual es verdadero.

Comment: Invalid numeric literal in .../.../... on line 29. LINEA 29: $vm= 08;

Comment: No, porque es igual o despues de 8-8-2018 y antes del 9-8-18 osea que si estamos a 9-9 no tendria porque verse, si ya pasó esa fecha

Comment: por eso mismo bro, la logica ahi esta mal, ya que esa fecha es menor que la actual, por ende la condiciones true, tendrias que intercambiar de posiciones o cambiar de operador

Comment: Como hago entonces, que se muestre de una fecha, por ejemplo 01-05-2018 hasta el 01-09-2018

Comment: Listo bro prueba la actualizacion que deje, ya que necesitas operar fechas quizas lo mas apropiado es que lo uses asi... me cuentas

Comment: No logro entender ese código, puse "+10" para poder ver la condicion y no me aparece

Comment: Algo no entiendo, estoy poniendo 2 veces lo mismo, " `("01-08-2018" >= $fecha || $fecha <= $nuevafecha)` " osea que digo que se muestre todos los dias menos los domingos, y que ademas si es entre la fecha "01-08-2018" en adelante, pero despues no tiendo la variable que pusiste. Es como que se contradice, no se va a mostrar nunca.

Comment: Pero esto no tiene nada que ver con lo que estaba buscando al principio, queria sumarle a un numero que puse en una variable,por ejemplo `$num1= 01;` y a ese "01" sumarle dias, y que php lo tome como si en realidad la variable dijiera POR EJEMPLO "13"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82942/discussion-between-srjj-and-matiphp).